# Limit on multiple rows insert

Tags: sqlite

Since version 3.7.11 SQLite supports enhanced INSERT syntax to allow multiple rows to be inserted via the VALUES clause.

http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html

Is there any limit on how many values can be inserted in a single statement? (for e.g. 500)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQLite handles a multi-row INSERT like a compound SELECT.
The limit for that [is indeed 500](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_compound_select).

However, since [version 3.8.8](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_8.html),

> the number of rows in a VALUES clause is no longer limited by SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT.

Answer (score 5):

According to the official documentation, there are some limits actually:

1. [Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_sql_length)

   The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to **1000000 bytes**.
2. [Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number)

   The number of host parameters (aka tokens) - either named, unnamed or numbered - is limited to SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to **999 items**.