# SQLite stack overflow when running a bulk INSERT OR REPLACE with 500 rows: why?

Tags: sqlite, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, stack-overflow

(See **update** at bottom of question for more to-the-point info.)

---

My code is constructing a SQL bulk `INSERT OR REPLACE` query with 500 rows (4 int32 and 2 int64 fields, for a total of 6 columns).  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860818/368896) and from experience, I know that the maximum limit for bulk insert of rows in SQLite is 500 rows.

A shortened example of the bulk insert query that my program is constructing, but with only 2 rows, is:

> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "VG_INSTANCE_DATA_B" (`year`, `yield`, `ccode`,
>   `month`, `DATETIME_ROW_START`, `DATETIME_ROW_END`) VALUES (1800,
>   6.9400000000000004, 2, 1, -5364662400000, -5333126400000), (1800, 6.9400000000000004, 2, 2, -5364662400000, -5333126400000)

The query is prepared in SQLite via `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`.

When the program builds & runs in Visual Studio 2013's debugger, and when there are 500 inserts in the bulk insert statement, the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` function crashes with a stack overflow, with internal SQLite functions being called over and over in a cycle.

When I decrease the **number** of bulk-inserted rows to 400, however, the stack overflow condition disappears.

I attempted to increase the stack size by *a factor of 10* by passing `/F 10000000` to the compiler and `/STACK 10000000` to the linker.  However, it had no effect.  I suspect that something else is going on - and that my stack is not really overflowing (it is hard for me to see how 500 rows at 20 bytes or so per row could cause a stack overflow just due to the amount of *data*, and as noted, there shouldn't be a stack overflow due to the internal function calls in SQLite, because otherwise SQLite would not claim to support 500 inserts in a bulk insert statement).

Can someone please explain why there is a stack overflow crash during the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` for a bulk insert of 500 rows (each containing only 6 reasonably-sized columns), when the official SQLite limit for a bulk insert is 500?  (Note: I also tested 499, and it still crashed with a stack overflow exception.  It is known not to crash at 400, though.)

Thanks!

---

**Update:** I have debugged into sqlite3.c and by using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480444/368896) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747499/368896), actually added code to calculate the stack usage, and placed a breakpoint at the point where the stack overflow occurs.

Two comments.

- SQLite does a RECURSIVE call for bulk inserts.  I.e., 500 rows in the bulk insert = 500 recursions into the set of functions involved, bringing the stack deeper and deeper.  (I do not know if the Release-mode compiler optimizes away the recursion, or not.)
- The stack is *legitimately* reaching the default 1 MB limit in Debug mode.  The crash definitely occurs at the single function call that brings the stack size over 1 MB (I know this by using the above-linked code to calculate the stack usage at the point of the stack overflow).

---

**Addendum 2**

Important info: my bulk query is actually `INSERT OR REPLACE`, and the stack overflow crash occurs in a recursive `SELECT` query.  This `SELECT` query is related to the `REPLACE` part of my bulk `INSERT` statement.  Therefore, I think it's likely that the relevant cause of the problem is the `REPLACE`, not the `INSERT`.  (See comments below this question for some more details, including timing.)

I have updated the title to reflect this.

Comment: Consider preparing a parameterized query that inserts a single row, then running it 500 times, with different values bound to parameters. The way you do it adds significant overhead: first you have to serialize all your values into one huge string, then SQLite has to parse them right back.

Comment: Works for me. Which SQLite version? (Could you update?) Which functions loop?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I have programmed it *both* ways - (1) with a prepared statement and parameterized queries, and (2) with bulk `insert` statement, and the latter appears *significantly* faster.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Make sure you enclose all runs of single-row insert in an explicit transaction: run `BEGIN` before, and `COMMIT` after. Otherwise, every individual row is inserted in its own implicit transaction, and committing a transaction is expensive with SQLite (it ensures that the data is physically written to disk surface).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I have also done that, in fact.  I wrap all 500 (or 400) inserts with the prepared statement inside a single explicit transaction.

Comment: I have discovered that the stack overflow is legitimate.  SQLite internally performs a *recursion* when implementing a bulk insert, rather than a loop; and in fact with 500 rows it is easy for the default 1 MB stack size on Windows to be reached.  I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: I have posted another question about how to increase the stack size in Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585073/how-to-increase-stack-size-for-a-thread-in-qt-qthreadsetstacksize-seems-no

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - My timing results are in. **(1) Bulk insert** (500 rows in one insert statement): 200,000 rows in ~15 seconds **(2) A single prepared statement** (a loop over 1,000 rows at a time, each loop wrapped in a transaction): ~1.5 hours **(3) A single prepared statement** with a single transaction over all 200,000 rows: ~1.5? hours, all time spent committing the transaction **(4) A single prepared statement** for all rows, with no transaction: ~1.5? hours **(5) No prep. statement**, transaction every 500 rows: many hours. I'm surprised (1) is so much faster. I hope to post a question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Important addendum: My queries are actually `INSERT OR REPLACE` (for the bulk version) and `UPDATE` followed by `INSERT` (if the update acted on 0 rows) (for the prepared statement version).  This might explain my numbers, as SQLite3 does spend "a lot" of time running a `SELECT` to handle the bulk call, and presumably must also do this in the prepared statement version - perhaps this eats up the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Must be something about your database schema and/or the exact queries you run. In my experience, just plain inserting 200,000 rows would take a couple of minutes, if that - certainly not hours. In any case, I suggest you post to [`sqlite-users` mailing list](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/sqlite-users). Many SQLite developers, including Dr. Hipp, are hanging out there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I have, I think, conclusively shown that it is the `UPDATE` part of my "first attempt `UPDATE`, then `INSERT`" that is causing nearly 100% of the time.  I have confirmed by simply removing the `UPDATE` part, and then the query with prepared statement runs comparably to the bulk insert (though it might be faster - I haven't timed it directly in comparison).  The "key" fields are NOT indexed in my case which easily explains the time spent by the `UPDATE` portion.  So it is the `UPDATE`, not the `INSERT`, that is the source of the issue.  Thanks!